# Gulp default task unable to compress after copy

Tags: gulp, gulp-uglify

At first I thought this was related to dependency of tasks so I went with run-sequence and even tried defining dependencies within tasks themselves. But I cannot get the `compress` task to run after `copy`. Or, even if it says it did finish the compress task, the compression only works if I run compress in the task runner inside visual studio by itself. What else can I try to get it to compress after copy?

```
/// <binding BeforeBuild='default' />
/*
This file is the main entry point for defining Gulp tasks and using Gulp plugins.
Click here to learn more. https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=518007
*/

var gulp = require("gulp");
var debug = require("gulp-debug");
var del = require("del");
var uglify = require("gulp-uglify");
var pump = require("pump");
var runSequence = require("run-sequence");

var paths = {
    bower: "./bower_components/",
    lib: "./Lib/"
};

var modules = {
    "store-js": ["store-js/dist/store.legacy.js"],
    "bootstrap-select": [
        "bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.css",
        "bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.js",
        "bootstrap-select/dist/js/i18n/*.min.js"
    ]
}

gulp.task("default", function (cb) {
    runSequence("clean", ["copy", "compress"], cb);
});

gulp.task("clean",
    function () {
        return del.sync(["Lib/**", "!Lib", "!Lib/ReadMe.md"]);
    });

gulp.task("compress",
    function (cb) {
        pump([
            gulp.src(paths.lib + "**/*.js"),
            uglify(),
            gulp.dest(paths.lib)
        ], cb);
    });

gulp.task("copy",
    function (cb) {
        prefixPathToModules();
        copyModules();
        cb();
    });

function prefixPathToModules() {
    for (var moduleIndex in modules) {
        for (var fileIndex in modules[moduleIndex]) {
            modules[moduleIndex][fileIndex] = paths.bower + modules[moduleIndex][fileIndex];
        }
    }
}

function copyModules() {
    for (var files in modules) {
        gulp.src(modules[files], { base: paths.bower })
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.lib));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with runSequence. But why don't you try the following. By this way your default task depends on compress and compress depends on copy. So, 'copy' will run first and then 'compress'

```
gulp.task('default', ['copy','compress'], function(cb){});

gulp.task('compress',['copy'], function(cb){});
```

Gulp returns a steam , since you are calling it in a for loop the stream is returned during the first iteration itself.

Update your copyModule to the following and you can try either runSequence like posted by Kirill or follow my approach

```
   function copyModules() {
            var inputFileArr = [];
            for (var files in modules) { 
              inputFileArr = inputFileArr.concat(modules[files]);
            };
        return gulp.src(inputFileArr, { base: paths.bower })
                .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.lib));       
    }
```

Comment: Tried this as well as the answer above, the log reads 


[08:11:57] Starting 'copy'...
[08:11:57] Finished 'copy' after 15 ms
[08:11:57] Starting 'compress'...
[08:11:58] Finished 'compress' after 4.47 ms
[08:11:58] Starting 'default'...
[08:11:58] Finished 'default' after 4.53 μs

but the final file size is not the compressed size. But if I run the compress task by itself then the final size is the compressed size. Not sure why.

Comment: Can you try to output the file to a different location.

Comment: Hmm, so I tried redirecting the output in compress to gulp.dest("./bin") and I should expect to see it in the bin directory correct? I don't see anything there.

Comment: Hmm that's weird. Can you try running individual task one after another. And see whether the results match after running each task. 1 clean - check the result, 2 copy , 3 compress

Comment: Yes, running individually everything works normally. Could it perhaps have to do with the for loop function that copy runs to actually copy the files? I feel like the issue might be looping related?

Comment: @uioporqwerty, Perhaps. gulp.src returns stream, so collect all you paths to one array and try without loop

Comment: Yes group the file paths into an array and then pass the final array to gulp.src

Comment: @KirillMatrosov Man you beat me to it by a minute

Answer (score 0):

You use [run-sequence](https://github.com/OverZealous/run-sequence) and your code

```
runSequence("clean", ["copy", "compress"], cb);
```

run in such order

1. clean
2. copy and compress in parallel *// that's why your code compresses nothing, because you have not copied files yet*
3. cb

Write like this and **compress** will be **after copy**

```
runSequence("clean", "copy", "compress", cb);
```

Comment: Tried this as well and if I run the default task the compress step never happens. :(